# Update text in a field on user profile

Tags: powershell-extensions

We are on Sitecore 8.1.3 and have a user profile where personal links are stored as a path unfortunately and when the page gets move (not too often) the personal link is broken.

For now we would like to run a powershell script to find and replace the path ("Common/menu" to "Shared/WestCafeteria")".  I have a find/replace script for the content tree, but not sure the path of all the user information and if that process should be used.

Attached image may be helpful (I removed the path in the personal link area).
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Personal Links data sample:

{"ID":"{66666CC6-C66C-66B3-6666-666A6D6AB666}","Title":"Cafeteria menus","TargetID":"{66666666-B666-4666-A666-6666666666B17}","TargetUrl":"/departments-services/support-services/nutritional-services/dining-locations","TargetWin":"_top"}

Comment: Can't quite make out the format you are using in the Personal Links field from the screenshot. It looks like json? Can you provide more details on the format?

Comment: Added data sample

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Get-User` command in SPE to get a collection of users to process, and then these are retrieved as an enumeration of `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User`, which gives you access to the custom profile.

This is a sample script which fill find all extranet users and update them, you can alter the configuration at the top of the script to change the find/replace values. It just uses a simple string replacement.

```powershell
# Configuration
$profileFieldName = "PersonalLinks"
$searchFor = "Common/menu"
$replaceWith = "Shared/WestCafeteria"
$userFilter = "extranet\*"

# Script
$users = Get-User -Filter $userFilter

foreach ( $user in $users )
{
    Write-Host "Updating $($user.Name)"

    # Get the custom field value
    $links = $user.Profile.GetCustomProperty($profileFieldName)

    # Update the value
    $links = $links -replace $searchFor, $replaceWith

    # Save the value back into the user
    $user.Profile.SetCustomProperty($profileFieldName, $links)
}
```

Note that the `Get-User` command supports partial matching on name, and also a `ResultPageSize` property to limit the results, which you may want to bear in mind if the size of your user-base is large.

Answer (score 4):

To get user information, you have to get the user (you can use Sitecore API or SPE cmldet) and read properties.
My example user:

[image]

**How to read it in SPE.**

[image]

**code:**

```powershell
$user = Get-User "sitecore\a"
$user.Profile.SerializedData
```

To update/save settings simply update the field/property

[image]